# I am having a problem with the installation of spaCy

Tags: windows, spacy

I am trying install spaCy but it says no module named spacy

I used python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md command in my terminal although it says " No module named spaCy". when I write the spacy info command it outputs the information so I have installed spacy successfully. Could someone please help me figure out what else I could do.

Answer (score 1):

That error is appearing because it is very likely that you indeed, do not have spaCy installed. Here is one way to have spaCy installed in your system (I will run the commands for a Linux-based system):

```
# Create a virtual environment
python -m venv my_venv

# Activate the previously created virtual environment
source my_venv/bin/activate

# Install spacy
pip install spacy

# Download `en_core_web_md`
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

If `python` triggers and error like `bash: python: command not found`, then try with `python3`. You should be set by now.

Hope it helps.